# Many-to-Many relationship configuration for EF Core with two DbContexts for a single DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have to define many to many relationship in Postgres db via EF Core between entity "User" and "GeoArea". User and GeoArea have their own DbContexts and both are used in the application on multiple places.

User entities are stored in the table "Users" located in scheme "Users" (`Users.Users`). GeoArea entities are stored in the table "GeoAreas" in scheme "Geo" (`Geo.GeoArea`).
Both tables already exists.

This design was given to me by the previous developers.

How to configure EF Core DBContexts to have many to many relationship between Users and GeoAreas?
Here is the C# stub code for User and GeoArea classes:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    // public ICollection<GeoArea> Areas { get; set; }
}

public class GeoArea
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // public ICollection<User> Users{ get; set; }
}

public class UsersDbContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersDbContext(DbContextOptions<UsersDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Users");
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users").HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(u => u.UserNameName);
    }
}

public class GeoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GeoArea> Areas { get; set; }

    public GeoDbContext(DbContextOptions<GeoDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Geo");
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new GeoAreaConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class GeoAreaConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<GeoArea>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GeoArea> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("GeoAreas").HasKey(ga => ga.Id);
        builder.Property(ga => ga.Id).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(ga => ga.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

### The goal

Define the many to many relationship between Users and GeoAreas with the minimal possible impact on the current code base with the minimal future design restrictions (*I want to maintain maximal flexibility*).

### One possible solution

```cs
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserGeoArea> UserGeoAreas { get; set; }
}

public class GeoArea
{
    public int GeoAreaId { get; set; }
    public string GeoAreaName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserGeoArea> UserGeoAreas { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserGeoArea>()
        .HasKey(uga => new { uga.UserId, uga.GeoAreaId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserGeoArea>()
        .HasOne(uga => uga.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.UserGeoAreas)
        .HasForeignKey(uga => uga.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserGeoArea>()
        .HasOne(uga => uga.GeoArea)
        .WithMany(g => g.UserGeoAreas)
        .HasForeignKey(uga => uga.GeoAreaId);
}
```

### Problems

1. I have to generate at least two migration from 2 DbContexts (`UserDbContext` and `GeoAreaDbContext`) => *I smell problems ahead*
2. When I try to generate a migration from one of the existing DbContext with M:N relation configured, the migration creates the other entity table in the first context, e.g. for a migration from `GeoAreaDbContext`, the migration creates "Geo.Users" table.
3. There are existing migrations for `UserDbContext` and `GeoAreaDbContext`.
4. Managing of transactions across multiple DbContexts
5. Future migrations from `UserDbContext` and `GeoAreaDbContext` when entities are extended by `ICollection`s.

### Questions

1. It is feasible by configuring just `UserDbContext` and `GeoAreaDbContext`? If so, how?
2. How about future migrations derived from `UserDbContext` and `GeoAreaDbContext`?
3. What are possible future problems if I create a new entity & DbContext (`UserGeoAreaDbContext`).

---

I know that this use of two DbContext is unusual, but I have to play with cards which I have.

Any valuable feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You can't use two DbContexts like this. A DbContext isn't a database connection. A DbContext is a **multi**-entity Unit-of-Work, that should contain all the entities needed for a specific scenario/use-case/bounded context. Using different contexts makes sense if you want to use different types and tables for specific scenarios but the contexts need to contain all the entities needed for that scenario

Comment: You can add entity to desired context but [exclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#excluding-parts-of-your-model) from migrations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your answer. I've updated my question (there are existing migration for both existing contexts). Could you elabore about why I could not use two DbContext like this? To be clear here - I pretty much agree with you, I would never design it like that, but I have to work with what I have. I need to find some feasible solution, or/and provide some solid arguments for my supervisors why this single M:N relationship is not a matter of 1 MD work, but rather 10-20 MDs and rewriting 1/5 of backend.

Comment: Because EF just doesn't work that way. A DbContext is the "thing" that contains all entities, relations and metadata, it's not a database model, schema or container. There's no other "thing" that could hold relations between two DbContext instances

Comment: `I have to generate at least two migration` *that's* the real problem. The two DbContexts are used as database models for scripting, the way a `dacpac` or Database Project in ADS would be used. EF Migrations are a simple tool, not meant for complex scenarios. You should probably do what Svyatoslav Danyliv says and exclude the common entities from one of the DbContexts

Comment: I don't get the whole idea about exclusion from migration, because I don't see use in my case. It excludes whole entity and my DbContexts have single entity.

Comment: @KUTlime I do it often with Identity tables. They're in a separate db from my app db. If I need to tie the identity tables (usually users) to my app tables, I create a users table in my app db and link them via the guid. If you combine your two contexts it will only cause you headaches especially with FK references. Pretty soon, you'll have both contexts into one which defeats the purpose of splitting them.